# Missing usbserial driver

Tags: debian, drivers, usb

I am looking for the usbserial driver: “option” for Debian Jessie and armel architecture.

Is there a package that contains this and other usbserial drivers?

Where is the source-code for this driver located?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Debian Packages Search results](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=armel&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=option.ko), it's available in the following packages:

```
linux-image-3.11-2-iop32x
linux-image-3.11-2-ixp4xx
linux-image-3.11-2-kirkwood
linux-image-3.11-2-mv78xx0
linux-image-3.11-2-orion5x
linux-image-3.11-2-versatile
```

If you are using an armel kernel other than that, you'll need to use the [linux debsrc](http://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/linux) to build your own package.

Comment: The source-code for the kernel I am using had the missing drivers. So I was able build a new kernel where the missing drivers where included.